# Losing navbar css after toggling menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My responsive navbar is having an issue. When I click the toggle when the screen is small, it responds and opens up the hidden navigation menu's, but the menus don't have the original css that is attached the navbar. Any help would be appreciated.

CSS:

```
<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #232526;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
  margin: 0em;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
ul.topnav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.8);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #232526;
}
ul.topnav li{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  color: #666666;
  padding: 1.167em 1.333em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #232526;}
ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.3);}
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
a.navbar-brand{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
}
img{
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 16.667em;
}
ul.imgcont{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4.167em 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.imgcont li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
ul.imgcont li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.1);
  border: 0.083em solid #232526;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
footer{
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.8);
  text-align: center; /*centers all of cooter */
  height: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #232526;
}
footer ul.right li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888888;
}
.left, .right{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}
.left li{
  text-align: right; /*aligns right within center */
  color: #888888;
}
.right li{
  text-align: left;
}
.material-icons.md-14{
  font-size: 1.167em;
}
.sliding-middle-out {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sliding-middle-out:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 0.167em;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
#home.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:grey;
}
#homer.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:black;
}
#warrior.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C79C6E;
}
#druid.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FF7D0A;
}
#priest.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#paladin.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#F58CBA;
}
#hunter.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:darkgreen;
}
#mage.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#69CCF0  ;
}
#shaman.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#0070DE;
}
#warlock.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#9482C9;
}
#rogue.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFF569;
}
#minions.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C41F3B;
}
#spells.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#A330C9;
}
#home.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:grey;
}
#warrior.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C79C6E;
}
#druid.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FF7D0A;
}
#priest.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#paladin.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#F58CBA;
}
#hunter.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#ABD473
}
#mage.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#69CCF0  ;
}
#shaman.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#0070DE;
}
#warlock.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#9482C9;
}
#rogue.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFF569;
}
#minions.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C41F3B;
}
#spells.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#A330C9;
}
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;} /* makes navbar disapearr */
  ul.topnav li.icon { /* creates the block for the toggle */
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1216px) { /* These are here to fix the overlap issue */
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4.167em 0 12.500em 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1083px) {
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8.333em 0 12.500em 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4.167em 0 170px 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:413px) {
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4.167em 0 12.500em 0;
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Header</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Cardspoiler.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a id="homer" class="sliding-middle-out navbar-brand" href="Home.html">Cardspoiler</a></li>
    <li><a id="home" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Home.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">home</i>Home</a></li> <!-- using the googleapis.com stylesheet -->
    <li><a id="warrior" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Warrior.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">usb</i>Warrior</a></li>
    <li><a id="druid" class="sliding-middle-out active" href="Druid.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">brightness_high</i>Druid</a></li>
    <li><a id="priest" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Priest.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">add_circle</i>Priest</a></li>
    <li><a id="paladin" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Paladin.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">star_half</i>Paladin</a></li>
    <li><a id="hunter" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Hunter.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">my_location</i>Hunter</a></li>
    <li><a id="mage" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Mage.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">whatshot</i>Mage</a></li>
    <li><a id="shaman" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Shaman.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">opacity</i>Shaman</a></li>
    <li><a id="warlock" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Warlock.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">person_outline</i>Warlock</a></li>
    <li><a id="rogue" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Rogue.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">visibility_off</i>Rogue</a></li>
    <li><a id="minions" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Minions.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">keyboard_arrow_up</i>Minions</a></li>
    <li><a id="spells" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Spells.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">keyboard_arrow_down</i>Spells</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:30px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
  <main>
  <ul class="imgcont">
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out" href="../Cards/1/Jade_Idol.html"><img src="../Cards/1/Jade_Idol_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/1/Mark_of_the_Lotus.html"><img src="../Cards/1/Mark_of_the_Lotus_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/3/Celestial_Dreamer.html"><img src="../Cards/3/Celestial_Dreamer_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/3/Jade_Blossom.html"><img src="../Cards/3/Jade_Blossom_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/3/Pilfered_Power.html"><img src="../Cards/3/Pilfered_Power_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/4/Jade_Spirit.html"><img src="../Cards/4/Jade_Spirit_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/5/Lotus_Agents.html"><img src="../Cards/5/Lotus_Agents_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/5/Lunar_Visions.html"><img src="../Cards/5/Lunar_Visions_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/5/Virmen_Sensei.html"><img src="../Cards/5/Virmen_Sensei_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/6/Aya_Blackpaw.html"><img src="../Cards/6/Aya_Blackpaw_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/6/Jade_Behemoth.html"><img src="../Cards/6/Jade_Behemoth_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/10/Kun_the_Forgotten_King.html"><img src="../Cards/10/Kun_the_Forgotten_King_S.png" ></a></li>
  </ul>
</main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <ul class="left hidden-xs">
      <li><a style="text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;">CARDSPOILER.COM</li>
      <li><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;">Freedom to know</a></li>
        <li>We are here to bring you visual, leaked spoilers for all of the cards you love within a simple gallery setting.</li>
          <li><a href="mailto:help@cardspoiler.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size: 10px;">CONTACT US</a>
            <a href="../../Privacy_Policy.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size: 10px;">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="MSoG.html">Mean Streets of Gadgetzan</a></li>
            <li><a href="ONiK.html">One Night in Karazhan</a></li>
            <li><a href="WotOG.html">Whispers of the Old Gods</a></li>
            <li><a href="tLoE.html">The League of Explorers</a></li>
            <li><a href="TGT.html">The Grand Tournament</a></li>
            <li><a href="BrM.html">Blackrock Mountain</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
      <!-- SCRIPTS -->
      <script src="../../Cardspoiler.js"></script>


      </html>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += "responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing `.topnav.responsive` in your CSS, but adding the string "responsive" to a class name of "topnav" in your JS, which results in `.topnavresponsive`. You can toggle the `.responsive` instead using `.classList.toggle()`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.classList.toggle("responsive");
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #232526;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
  margin: 0em;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
ul.topnav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.8);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #232526;
}
ul.topnav li{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  color: #666666;
  padding: 1.167em 1.333em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #232526;}
ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.3);}
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
a.navbar-brand{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
}
img{
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 16.667em;
}
ul.imgcont{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4.167em 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.imgcont li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
ul.imgcont li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.1);
  border: 0.083em solid #232526;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
footer{
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.8);
  text-align: center; /*centers all of cooter */
  height: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #232526;
}
footer ul.right li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888888;
}
.left, .right{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}
.left li{
  text-align: right; /*aligns right within center */
  color: #888888;
}
.right li{
  text-align: left;
}
.material-icons.md-14{
  font-size: 1.167em;
}
.sliding-middle-out {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sliding-middle-out:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 0.167em;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
#home.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:grey;
}
#homer.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:black;
}
#warrior.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C79C6E;
}
#druid.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FF7D0A;
}
#priest.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#paladin.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#F58CBA;
}
#hunter.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:darkgreen;
}
#mage.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#69CCF0  ;
}
#shaman.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#0070DE;
}
#warlock.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#9482C9;
}
#rogue.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFF569;
}
#minions.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C41F3B;
}
#spells.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#A330C9;
}
#home.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:grey;
}
#warrior.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C79C6E;
}
#druid.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FF7D0A;
}
#priest.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#paladin.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#F58CBA;
}
#hunter.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#ABD473
}
#mage.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#69CCF0  ;
}
#shaman.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#0070DE;
}
#warlock.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#9482C9;
}
#rogue.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#FFF569;
}
#minions.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#C41F3B;
}
#spells.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color:#A330C9;
}
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;} /* makes navbar disapearr */
  ul.topnav li.icon { /* creates the block for the toggle */
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1216px) { /* These are here to fix the overlap issue */
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4.167em 0 12.500em 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1083px) {
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8.333em 0 12.500em 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4.167em 0 170px 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:413px) {
  ul.imgcont{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4.167em 0 12.500em 0;
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Header</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Cardspoiler.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a id="homer" class="sliding-middle-out navbar-brand" href="Home.html">Cardspoiler</a></li>
    <li><a id="home" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Home.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">home</i>Home</a></li> <!-- using the googleapis.com stylesheet -->
    <li><a id="warrior" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Warrior.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">usb</i>Warrior</a></li>
    <li><a id="druid" class="sliding-middle-out active" href="Druid.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">brightness_high</i>Druid</a></li>
    <li><a id="priest" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Priest.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">add_circle</i>Priest</a></li>
    <li><a id="paladin" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Paladin.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">star_half</i>Paladin</a></li>
    <li><a id="hunter" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Hunter.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">my_location</i>Hunter</a></li>
    <li><a id="mage" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Mage.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">whatshot</i>Mage</a></li>
    <li><a id="shaman" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Shaman.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">opacity</i>Shaman</a></li>
    <li><a id="warlock" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Warlock.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">person_outline</i>Warlock</a></li>
    <li><a id="rogue" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Rogue.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">visibility_off</i>Rogue</a></li>
    <li><a id="minions" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Minions.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">keyboard_arrow_up</i>Minions</a></li>
    <li><a id="spells" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Spells.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">keyboard_arrow_down</i>Spells</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:30px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
  <main>
  <ul class="imgcont">
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out" href="../Cards/1/Jade_Idol.html"><img src="../Cards/1/Jade_Idol_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/1/Mark_of_the_Lotus.html"><img src="../Cards/1/Mark_of_the_Lotus_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/3/Celestial_Dreamer.html"><img src="../Cards/3/Celestial_Dreamer_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/3/Jade_Blossom.html"><img src="../Cards/3/Jade_Blossom_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/3/Pilfered_Power.html"><img src="../Cards/3/Pilfered_Power_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/4/Jade_Spirit.html"><img src="../Cards/4/Jade_Spirit_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/5/Lotus_Agents.html"><img src="../Cards/5/Lotus_Agents_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/5/Lunar_Visions.html"><img src="../Cards/5/Lunar_Visions_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/5/Virmen_Sensei.html"><img src="../Cards/5/Virmen_Sensei_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/6/Aya_Blackpaw.html"><img src="../Cards/6/Aya_Blackpaw_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/6/Jade_Behemoth.html"><img src="../Cards/6/Jade_Behemoth_S.png" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="sliding-middle-out"href="../Cards/10/Kun_the_Forgotten_King.html"><img src="../Cards/10/Kun_the_Forgotten_King_S.png" ></a></li>
  </ul>
</main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <ul class="left hidden-xs">
      <li><a style="text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;">CARDSPOILER.COM</li>
      <li><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;">Freedom to know</a></li>
        <li>We are here to bring you visual, leaked spoilers for all of the cards you love within a simple gallery setting.</li>
          <li><a href="mailto:help@cardspoiler.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size: 10px;">CONTACT US</a>
            <a href="../../Privacy_Policy.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size: 10px;">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="MSoG.html">Mean Streets of Gadgetzan</a></li>
            <li><a href="ONiK.html">One Night in Karazhan</a></li>
            <li><a href="WotOG.html">Whispers of the Old Gods</a></li>
            <li><a href="tLoE.html">The League of Explorers</a></li>
            <li><a href="TGT.html">The Grand Tournament</a></li>
            <li><a href="BrM.html">Blackrock Mountain</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
      <!-- SCRIPTS -->
      <script src="../../Cardspoiler.js"></script>


      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is making the class `topnavresponsive`. Just need to add a space to start of the `responsive` string so it comes out `"topnav responsive"`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```